# Componente REACT retornado por una promesa

Tags: reactjs, promesas, componentes

estoy intentando hacer una función asíncrona y debo retornar un elemento generado por el resultado de una promesa y no puedo, me sale el error:

-"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."-

Seria hacer algo asi que funcione:

```
class componente {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 {
                     promesa.then(result => {
                         for(n in result){
                             return <p>{result[n]}</p>
                         }
                     }) 
                 }
            </div>
```

)
}
}

¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda?

Comment: Debes poner el codigo, sino como podriamos ayudarte?

Comment: no puse el codigo porque es de un proyecto entero, seria dificil de entender y tendria que explicar todo para poder ayudar

Comment: actualizare la publicacion con un ejemplo para explicarme

Comment: acabo de modificar la publicación por si ahora se puede entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `React`, necesitas actualizar el estado para que el componente vuelva a hacer un `render`. No puedes esperar a que recibir una promesa y que se actualice mágicamente.

```
class componente {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            'result': []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        promesa.then(result => {
            this.setState({'result': result})
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 {
                    this.state.result.map((r) => <p>{r}</p>)
                 }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Para ello, añadí un estado a tu componente. El estado tiene la propiedad result, la cual se actualizara con el resultado de tu promesa.

La promesa llamará a `setState`, y posteriormente, tras actualizar el estado, el componente volverá a hacer un render.

Comment: Muchas gracias!